# Input exceptions for integer division (Java)

Tags: java, exception, integer, division

This code is supposed to catch exceptions when dividing 24 by the supplied denominator from the input stream. It's needs to catch exceptions such as when dividing by 0, if a word like "hello" is entered by the user, or anything else weird that the user may input. Also when a decimal is entered, the return value has to be an integer. If any exception is caught, the program has to ask the user to enter another integer in until a valid one is entered.

The problem I'm having is that the program is not catching the exception where a word may be entered or a decimal may be entered. What am I doing wrong.

```
  public class Division {

  public int quotient(int numerator){
  boolean flag = false;
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  int denom = 0;      
  while(flag==false){
      denom = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
      try{
          int q = numerator/denom;
      } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
          System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
          continue;
      } catch(InputMismatchException ime){
          System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
          continue;
      } catch(ArithmeticException ae){
          System.out.print("Enter a non-zero integer:");
          continue;
      }
      flag=true;
  }
  return numerator/denom;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("Enter an integer (although you can make mistakes): ");
      System.out.println("The quotient is " + new Division().quotient(24));
      System.out.println("Done!");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this statement

```
denom = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
```

into the `try/catch` block so that it is caught in the `NumberFormatException` block

i.e.

```
try {
    denom = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
    ...
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
    continue;
} catch (...) {
```

Read: [The try block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, if I enter a decimal, such as 6.2, I want it to return 4 as the answer. But right now it thinks that is an exception. How do I fix that?

Comment: Change the variable type to a `double`. Will be a good exercise :)

Answer (score 2):

A `catch` statement will only capture the exceptions launched *inside* its `try` block. Move the `Integer.parseInt` statement inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

You need `try{` to occur BEFORE `denom = Integer.parseInt(s.next());`, not after, so that the exception can actually get caught.